# Linking to an ID on the same page cuts of above content

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Hi Im building a onepager website. The navigation consists of "Home, Work, Approach, Contact" As it is a onepager, as you click the navigation, i want it to jump to that ID. It does jump to the right ID, although all of the above content gets cut off and the website background gets pushed down.

Heres my code

```
    <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="home" class="synkron">SYNKRON</a>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="home" id="home" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#featured-project" id="work" class="nav-link">WORK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#Our-work" id="approach" class="nav-link">APPROACH</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#contact-us" id="contact" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

```
    <section id="contact-us" class="contact-section sektioner">
            <div class="contact-text-area">
                <h1 class="contact">CONTACT</h1>
            </div>
          </section>
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example (use snippet button)

Comment: Please show the relevant CSS. For example, how are you setting that background that jumps down? Is there a fixed setting somewhere?

Comment: I tried out your code and it works. I did put a lot of random text inside some p tags before your section tag. Then when I click on the 'CONTACT' link the page jumped to the section.

Comment: If everything is on the same page as you view it in the browser you can't tell if it is working or not.

Comment: Yes it will jump to the right sektion, but I am not able to scroll back up. The code is to long for code snippet

Comment: @Mattyb hens is "minimal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem occurred when I added more than two SVG's to the page. Deleting then resolved the problem. Don't know how or why they affected internal links on the page.